# Python 2.7 subprocess returns nothing, exact command works in console

Tags: python, python-2.7, console, subprocess

I'm trying to execute the `strings` command inside of a Python script. I had it working for awhile, but mysteriously, it doesn't return anything when I use `subprocess.Popen` anymore.

Called from terminal

```
strings /path/to/.bashrc
# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval `dircolors`
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
# Some more alias to avoid making mistakes:
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'
shopt -u -o history
```

In Python shell:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['strings', '/path/to/.bashrc'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = proc.communicate()
```

The second returns nothing. Why?

Comment: Why are you using shell=True?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

Try using:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("strings /path/to/file", ...)
```

Comment: When I run that on a known text file (output.txt, confirmed via terminal) I get `"[Errorno 2] No such File Or Directory"`

Comment: Did you kept the 'shell=True'? If you don't use it, you need to specify the arguments as a list as you did initially.